# How to show the following about the infinite group?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Prove, or disprove the statement:

An infinite group $G$ can never act transitively on a finite set $X$.

What i know is that a group action $G \times X \to X$ is transitive if it possesses only a single group orbit, i.e., for every pair of elements $x$ and $y$, there is a group element $g$ such that  $gx=y$.

Comment: Every group has an action on a one-point set.

Comment: More generally, if $H$ is any group acting transitively on any set $X$, and $G$ is also any group, then $G \times H$ acts transitively on $X$ with $G$ in the kernel of the action.

Comment: So can i say that the above statement is incorrect? The trivial action of any group is one such transitive group action?

Comment: @MittalG yes if $X$ is just a point then any infinite group (say $G=\mathbb{Z}$) acts on $X$ trivially and transitively.

Comment: @Yanko What if $X$ has cardinality strictly greater than $1$?

Comment: @MittalG Then the answer is still yes but the trivial action will not suffice. For example if $X=\{a,b\}$ then you can take $G=\mathbb{Z}$ such that even integers acts trivially, and odd integers takes $a$ to $b$ and $b$ to $a$.

Comment: @Yanko But this is not a group action.

Comment: @MittalG it is. Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Lord Shark the Unknown (see comments) every infinite group acts on a set of size $1$.

If you require moreover that $X$ has cardinality greater than $1$ then you can still define a transitive action on $X$ by an infinite group.

Example: If $X=\{a,b\}$ we can define the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $X$ by

$$n.x = x$$
if $n$ is even, and
$$n.x = \cases{ a & x=b \\ b & x=a}$$
if $n$ is odd.

I claim that this is a group action:
The trivial element $0$ is even and it acts trivially. It is left to show that $g(hx)=(g+h)x$

If $n,m$ are even then $n+m$ is even and so $n(mx) = (n+m)x = x$.

If $n,m$ are odd then $n+m$ is even and we still have $n(m(x))=(n+m)x=x$.

If $n$ is odd and $m$ is even then $n+m$ is odd. In this case

$$n(m(a))=n(a)=b = (n+m)(a)$$
and
$$n(m(b))=n(b) = a = (n+m)(b)$$

Finally if $n$ is even and $m$ is odd then $n+m$ is odd. In this case

$$n(m(a))=n(b)=b = (n+m)(a)$$
$$n(m(b))=n(a)=a=(n+m)(b)$$

Thus in all cases we have that $n(m(x))=(n+m)x$ and so this really defines a group action.

The action is transitive of course because $\{0.x,1.x\} = \{a,b\}$ for all $x\in\{a,b\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Already @Yanko has given a very nice example but I will add something so that you can construct your own example.

Take any infinite group G acting on a finite set X. We know that every orbit is invariant under that action of G, so we can restrict our action on that orbit and that action will be transitive(why?). Of course this orbit is a finite set(as it is a subset of a finite set).

I will ended with a nice example here.

Example-: Consider an infinite group G with a finite index subgroup H. Then consider the action of G on co-sets of H. It will work(check)!